# WordPress running two queries together

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, geolocation

This is an events website that handles the location of each event relative to the users location and displays the distance in search results.

I'm using the [WP GeoQuery](https://github.com/fyaconiello/wp-geo-posts) extension to allow me to query based on distance. However, it doesn't work well with things like `tax_query`. So, I'm wondering if there's a way of running the `WP_GeoQuery` to query for events within a certain distance, then run the result of that through the normal `Wp_Query` to get it to filter for the correct taxonomies and other arguments?

Here's the Geo Query:

```
$url = "http://freegeoip.net/json/". $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] .'';
$geo = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

$geo_query = new WP_GeoQuery(array(
    // location stuff
    'latitude' => $geo[latitude], // User's Latitude (optional)
    'longitude' => $geo[longitude], // User's Longitude (optional)

    // radius breaks the query if using tax_query too
    'radius' => 25 // Radius to select for in miles (optional)
));
```

And here's the normal WP_Query:

```
// add query for title
        function title_filter( $where, &$wp_query ) {
            global $wpdb;
            if ( $search_term = $wp_query->get( 'title_like' ) ) {
                $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( like_escape( $search_term ) ) . '%\'';
            }
            return $where;
        }
        add_filter( 'posts_where', 'title_filter', 10, 2 );



        // dates to and from
        function date_from( $from ) {
            $from = str_replace("meta_key = 'date_%_start-date'", "meta_key LIKE 'date_%_start-date'", $from);
            return $from;
        }
        add_filter('posts_where', 'date_from');

        function date_to( $to ) {
            $to = str_replace("mt1.meta_key = 'date_%_end-date'", "mt1.meta_key LIKE 'date_%_end-date'", $to);
            return $to;
        }
        add_filter('posts_where', 'date_to');





        // convert date to yyyymmdd
        $date1 = str_replace('/', '-', $_POST['when']);
        $when = date("Ymd", strtotime($date1));

        $date2 = str_replace('/', '-', $_POST['when-2']);
        $when2 = date("Ymd", strtotime($date2));

    ?>

    <h1>Search</h1>

    <div class="events">

        <?php $args = array(  
            // general
            'post_type' => 'event',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 2,
            'paged' => $paged,

            // what input
            'title_like' => $_POST['what'],

            // category filter
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'main-cat',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $_POST['main-cat']
                )
            ),

            // date filter
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key' => 'date_%_start-date',
                    'value' => $when,
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'type' => 'DATE'
                ),
                array (
                    'key' => 'date_%_end-date',
                    'value' => $when2,
                    'compare' => '<=',
                    'type' => 'DATE'
                )
            ),


        );

        $temp = $wp_query;
        $wp_query = null;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        $wp_query->query('posts_per_page=2&post_type=event'.'&paged='.$paged);
```

When used individually they work fine. But I'm not sure how I can run one of them, then use the result to put through the other query. Is this even possible?

Comment: Have you tried to reset query after loop, wp_reset_query(); ?

Comment: I meant that I wanted to run both of these queries and return one set of results, instead of returning two sets of results on one page.

Comment: ok did you look where is keeping in database lattitude and longitude ?

Comment: It's actually in a couple of places at the moment. I have it in `wp_postmeta` with the keys `lat` and `long`. I also have it in it's own table called `lat_lng_post`with the keys `lat` and `lng`. They're in multiple places as I'm trying to figure out the best place for them.

Comment: you can get post meta in loop by this function get_post_meta(post_id,meta_key, true), if you want as one result user meta_query. if you want to get from lat_lng_post I guess you should use custom query with wpdb, can you provide me structure of that table how it is connected with wp_posts table ?

Comment: I want to actually query posts by the lat and long data, to work out the distance in miles from the users current location, not just display the lat and long on the page within the loop, which I think is where you're going with that?

Comment: ok try this 
array(
        'post_per_page' => 2,
         'paged' => $paged,
 'post_type' => 'event',
 'meta_query' => array(
  'relation' => 'AND',
  array(
   'key' => 'lat',
   'value' => '44.444',
   'compare' => '='
  ),
  array(
   'key' => 'long',
   'value' => '50.456',
                        'compare' => '='
  )
 )
);
$query = new Wp_Query($args)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the query I have is a little more complicated, it searches posts within a radius of the users lat and long, we're not after an exact match, but for lat and longs within day 25 miles of the users location.

Comment: No problem hope that I've helped you somehow :)